# Некорректная работа IDT Audio и проблемы с микрофоном

Tags: windows-7, аудио

Здравствуйте! 
Мучаюсь уже много недель над этой проблемой, очень надеюсь на вашу помощь!
Мой ноутбук Dell inspirion N5110, core i7, я чайник, так что не знаю что еще перечислить, старенький, вот и проблемы.[image: Предоставлю фото]

Дело в том, что купила новый микрофон для записи видео, установила, и сразу начались проблемы. Сначала микрофон вообще не работал на моем ноутбуке. Потом я долго шаманила, так долго, что не перечислю все, удаляла IDT audio, зачем-то пыталась загрузить Realtek, только потом почитала и поняла, что он просто мне не подходит:D,  восстанавливала систему, опять пыталась загрузить IDT audio, сначала он не находил файл, потом я все же нашла где и куда поставить недостающие файлы, потом скинула вообще драйвер до старой версии, и микрофон заработал! Но IDT Audio панель теперь не хочет открываться, как бы я не пыталась ее открыть, она игнорирует все мои действия.
В итоге, я не могу настроить микрофон, который ловит все посторонние шумы, внутренние звуки ноутбука и щелчки мыши.
Уже не знаю что и делать, заказала дешевенькую usb звуковую карту, но боюсь, она не решит проблемы с настройкой микрофона. Этим должна заниматься IDT audio, которая не работает.
Если для вашего понимания нужны будут еще скриншоты, я с радостью их выложу.
Можно попробовать удалить и снова загрузить, но боюсь что либо предпринимать, пока микрофон работает, не хочется все сломать нафиг.
Если есть какие-либо аналоги этой программы, которые помогут настроить микрофон, то пожалуйста, напишите как они называются. 
Прошу помочь разобраться с моей проблемой!
Заранее благодарю!

### Решение в комментариях

Comment: а ошибку какую-нибудь выдает, или просто не реагирует при попытке запустить IDT audio?

Comment: Раньше выдавал ошибку "Cannot find .startup file!" Но после того, как поместила в папку недостающие файлы, больше этой ошибки не было, но и не включался он так же. Уточнение, вот что я сделала, если это важно: Открыла C: \ Program Files \ IDT \ OEM \ Dell , нашла файл IDTNGUI.startup , скопировала его, и вставила в C: \ Program Files \ IDT \ OEM

Comment: Не реагирует, сколько бы не кликала мышью, пыталась открыть в контекстном меню на правую кнопку мыши, переносила ярлык и опять же пыталась открыть - ноль эмоций.

Comment: а диспетчер задач что показывает? в процессах

Comment: Добавила к теме скриншот, сама не разберусь

Comment: Попробуйте так для начала:
«Панель управления» --> «Звук» --> «Запись» (смотрим подключенные микрофоны, двойной клик по иконке с нужным микрофоном) --> «Свойства: Микрофона» --> «Улучшения» --> «Подавление шума» --> «Прослушать» (тестируем лучше или хуже, ну или любым другим способом можно протестить)

Comment: К сожалению у меня даже нет вкладки улучшения, скриншот я добавила в тему. На самом деле уже обшарила все свойства микрофона в данном окне

Comment: Вкладка "Дополнительно" --> "Формат по умолчанию" что стоит?
и в "Уровни" какое стоит значение?

Comment: Попыталась обновить драйвера, в итоге все же появились дополнительные функции, там и подавление эха есть, но вот микрофон теперь вообще не работает, ползунок стоит на месте, и проверить его опять же не получается(( скрин добавила в тему, это на тему формата по умолчанию, а в уровнях 100 и усиление микрофона на 10 дб, но их я тоже уже крутила и проверяла, в первую очередь. Теперь уже сама ничего делать не буду. Стоит скинуть обратно, чтобы микрофон заработал, или оставить пока как есть? Панель IDT все еще игнорирует

Comment: что делал бы я: 
1. удалил бы IDT
2. почистил реестр(на всякий случай)
3. обновил дрова на звуковую карту
4. перезагрузил комп

Comment: Все сделала, звук работает, вот только панель IDT теперь не отображается в панели управления (оборудования и звук). Стоит снова загрузить? В диспетчере устройств все же отображается, "Устройство с поддержкой High Definition Audio"

Comment: IDT не удаляли?

Comment: Удалила в панели управления. Нужно было в диспетчере устройств?Реестр тоже почистила

Comment: «Свойства: Микрофона» --> «Улучшения» --> «Подавление шума» появилось?
Шумы по прежнему есть?
Думаю ставить IDT не стоит

Comment: Улучшений и подавление шума не появилось, но звук вроде чистый, шума практически нет! IDT больше ставить не буду, думаю незначительные шумы исправит usb звуковая карта. Теперь все функционирует нормально :D Спасибо вам Огромное, без вас бы не справилась!)))

Comment: "Дополнительно" --> "Формат по умолчанию" я бы рекомендовал на dvd поставить. Впрочем как пожелаете)

Comment: Так и сделаю!))) Моя недельная головная боль, решили все за один вечер! Благодарю за помощь))))

Comment: На здоровье  :))